# How to write bytebuddy code for private List<@Min(3) @Max(7) String> myList

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I need to generate this field:

```
private List<@Min(3) @Max(7) String> myList
```

Without annotations I can do it with:

```
.defineField("myList", TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(List.class, String.class).build(), Visibility.PRIVATE)
```

How can I annotate type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest types from a builder and also build annotations

```
TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
  TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(List.class),
  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.rawType(String.class).annotate(
    AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Min.class).define("value", 3).build(),
    AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Max.class).define("value", 7).build()
  ).build()
).build();
```